# Phonegap Parse Plugin Installations are showing but notifications aren't being received

Tags: android, parsing, cordova, push-notification

I'm getting the installation show up in the Parse data browser, the right app name, version number, an installationId and I'm subscribing to a channel based on the users session ID, all that shows up in the right columns but the deviceToken column is empty (although I'm not sure if Android needs that or just iOS)

When I try and send a push from Parse, it shows the correct number of recipients, the status shows as **Done** in Parse, but the PN never arrives on the phone.

This is a Cordova 3.5.0 app, this is the code I'm using in the `deviceready` function. Again I'm not sure I need to get the installationID as I'm not using it - but all the tutorials I've seen seem to mention it after the initialize method:

```
// init parse
window.parsePlugin.initialize(
    "app_id", 
    "client_key",
    function() {
        console.log( 'PARSE INIT OK' );
        window.parsePlugin.getInstallationId(function(id) {
            installationID = id;        

        }, function(e) {
            console.log("Error Getting ID: " + e.code + " : " + e.message);
        })
    }, 
    function( e ) {
        console.log( 'PARSE FAILED' );
    }
);
```

I see the "PARSE INIT OK" message in logCat in Eclipse.

I've installed the plugin from this repo: https://github.com/benjie/phonegap-parse-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this at the moment by manually adding the following to my main activity:

```
// register device for parse
Parse.initialize(this, "app_id", "client_key");
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MyApp.class);
ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

It's working, but I'd rather not have to modify the main Activity class - I'm hoping I've done something simple wrong with the plugin, but this is working for the time being.

If I can find a way to get the plugin to use a hook to add the code to the onCreate class I'll update the answer